Regarding $\nabla \times (u \times v)$ and Sobolev Spaces
Greetings fellow members,

Let $\Omega$ be a bounded domain (open+connected) of $\mathbb{R}^3$. Let's consider $S(\Omega)$, a subspace of Sobolev $H^1(\Omega)$ defined by :
\begin{align*}
S(\Omega)=\{v \in H^1(\Omega)\,\mid\,\, \operatorname{div}(v)=0 \,\, \text{in} \,\, \Omega \, \text{ and } v \cdot n=0 \text{ on } \Gamma \}.
\end{align*}
For $u$ and $v$ in $S(\Omega)$, where does $u \times v$ belong to? And what about $\nabla \times (u \times v)$?

My guess is that, as $H^1(\Omega)$ embeds continuously in $L^p(\Omega)$ for all $ 1\leqslant p \leqslant 6$, the best we can hope for $u \times v$ is to be $L^3(\Omega)$ $\big(\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{6}=\frac{1}{3}\big)$. $\,$ So $\nabla \times (u \times v)$ belongs to $H^{-1}(\Omega)$, the dual of $H_0^1(\Omega)$.
Am I wrong ? And is there a chance for $\nabla \times (u \times v)$ to be $L^p(\Omega)$ (for a suitable $p$)?
Thank you, and best regards.

Welcome to math SE. Could edit your post to include some of your thought?

@AlainRemillard Done !

What exactly is $\times$?

@HyperbolicPDEfriend Hello sir, it's the cross product.

You might have to compute $\mathrm{div}(u \times v)$ and maybe use Hölder

If I am not mistaken $\nabla \times (u \times v)$ contains entries of the type
$$
\frac\partial{ \partial x_i}(u_jv_k).
$$
Using chain rule, we have
$$
\frac\partial{ \partial x_i}(u_jv_k) = v_k\frac\partial{ \partial x_i}u_j
+ u_j\frac\partial{ \partial x_i}v_k.
$$
Since $u,v \in H^1$, their partial derivatives are in $L^2$ and by Sobolev embedding, $u, v\in L^6$. This implies $\frac\partial{ \partial x_i}(u_jv_k) \in L^{3/2}$ by Hoelder inequality.
